# Перестал работать календарь (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, сделал недавно календарь по уроку для своего сайта. Слабо понимаю как он работает, по этому после изменений (а именно сменил название поля date на session_start_date и тип данных с date на string) он перестал работать. Точнее перестали выводится события в соответствующих датах. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Вывод календаря на страницу

```
<h1>Calendar</h1>
<div id="film_sessions">
  <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", session_start_date: @date.prev_month %>
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", session_start_date: @date.next_month %>
  </h2>
  <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %>
    <% if @film_sessions_by_date[date] %>
      <ul>
        <% @film_sessions_by_date[date].each do |film_session| %>
          <li><%= link_to film_session.session_name, film_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Метод для него

```
 def calendar
   @film_sessions = FilmSession.all
   @film_sessions_by_date = @film_sessions.group_by(&:session_start_date)
   @date = params[:session_start_date] ? Date.parse(params[:session_start_date]) : Date.today
 end
```

И формирование самого календаря

```
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end

  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end

    def week_rows
      weeks.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
          week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      classes = []
      classes << "today" if day == Date.today
      classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
      classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def weeks
      first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
      last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
      (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**

Выяснил, что проблема в этом блоке

```
    <% if @film_sessions_by_date[date] %>
      <ul>
        <% @film_sessions_by_date[date].each do |film_session| %>
          <li><%= link_to film_session.session_name, film_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
```

То есть выполняется код в else:

```
<% if @film_sessions_by_date[date] %>
  <ul>
    <% @film_sessions_by_date[date].each do |film_session| %>
      <li><%= link_to film_session.session_name, film_session %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Берите отладчик, идите по порядку.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала хотя бы вернуть тип полю date.

Comment: @cheops Очевидно, что если я верну все изменения назад, то все заработает) Хотелось бы перестроить решение чтобы все работало с новыми данными.

Comment: Буду благодарен, если подскажите что делает эта строчка @date = params[:session_start_date] ? Date.parse(params[:session_start_date]) : Date.today

Comment: @MaximCherevatov, может описать зачем понадобилось изменить тип на строковый (к названию параметра вопросов нет)? Строка выше проверяет имеется ли в GET/POST-параметрах session_start_date, если имеется формирует из этого параметра дату, если не имеется, берет текущую дату.

Comment: База данных postgresql постоянно выдавала ошибку и жаловалась на это поле. Долго не мог ее обойти, и решил изменив тип поля. Знаю что костыль, но временно помогло)

Comment: @cheops Обновил вопрос

Comment: У вас в "вопросе" (который, по сути, "отладьте за меня чужой код") нет ни одного сообщения об ошибке, из которого можно было бы отследить проблему. А если его нет, то нужно хотя бы "ожидание/реальность".

Comment: @D-side Я Вас понимаю) Но ошибки нету, страница открывается. Просто всегда срабатывает блок else. Теперь очевидно что проблема связана с строчкой <% if @film_sessions_by_date[date] %>

Comment: Вот берите отладчик, остановитесь на той строчке и посмотрите значения у всех участников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил изменив следующий код:

```
<h1>Calendar</h1>
<div id="film_sessions">
  <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", session_start_date: @date.prev_month %>
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", session_start_date: @date.next_month %>
  </h2>
  <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %>
    <% if @film_sessions %>
      <ul>
        <% @film_sessions.each do |film_session| %>
          <% if film_session.session_start_date == date.to_s %>
            <li><%= link_to film_session.session_name, film_session %></li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```